# Is Send Time Optimization available outside of Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein, email-studio

I have a client that is hoping to take advantage of Send Time Optimization for their large communications. I have two questions:

1. Is STO available outside of Journey Builder?
2. If I need to use Journey Builder, what is the max performance per hour I should expect? (eg. 25k sent per hour)

Thanks!
-Keith

Answer (score 1):

I would defer to this help doc: '[Einstein Send Time Optimization for Journey Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_einstein_sto.htm&type=5)'

> This feature is available to customers with Marketing Cloud Einstein terms for Corporate, Enterprise, or Pro edition accounts with the Journey Builder add-on. To use this activity, activate Einstein Send Time Optimization for your business unit.

There is not a way to leverage STO Outside journey builder currently

Also '[Optimize Journey Builder Performance](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_optimize_sending_in_journey_builder.htm&type=5)' & '[Journey Builder Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_builder_best_practices.htm&type=5)' if you are worried about preformance

> When a journey has no entry filter, you can admit up to 2 million contacts per hour. When a journey has an entry filter, you can admit up to 250,000 contacts per hour. Following these general guidelines promotes efficient hourly processing.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that a filter limited to 250k.